# import error on python script

Tags: python, import

I have a python script that has these import lines:

```
import os
import sys
import SA_auth_keys
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import API
from tweepy import Cursor
from tweepy.error import RateLimitError, TweepError
from optparse import OptionParser
import ast
```

When trying to run the script I have this Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "2_From_IDs_To_JSON.py", line 23, in <module>
    import SA_auth_keys
ImportError: No module named SA_auth_keys
```

How can I run the script?

Comment: you are missing a file `SA_auth_keys.py`. You should find it where you got the original script.

Comment: yes it was my mistake,
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try these 2 methods, which might solve your issue:

1. **[exec](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#execfile) command:** `execfile('SA_auth_keys.py')`
2. **Initiate a shell process:** `os.system('python SA_auth_keys.py')`.